# How to write the Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having one situation,

**Book Number | Book Authors | Publications | Versions**

Controls i used in above fields, label in Book No., Combo box in Book Authors, Label in Publications and Combo box in Versions.

The above is my UI, if i choose the book authors from the combo box(values in combo box are retrieving from db), the values of publications and versions should retrieve from the db based upon the item i choose from the combo box. The page should not refresh. How to write the stored procedure for this.

Comment: @Scorpion: I just tried select queries, but it's not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you really are asking the wrong question. There are a couple good answers here for how to write a select statement (via a stored procedure, or not).

However, getting the data from the database has little to do with to putting that data into the appropriate controls on your UI, and nothing to do with making sure the page does not refresh.

If you are really interested in how to how to write a stored procedure for a simple select statement, accept @MikaelEriksson's answer, but add appropriate SET statements to minimize future upgrade issues. You will also need to modify the column and table names to reflect your actual data (of course).

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetBooksByAuthorID
   @AuthorID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT B.BookName,
           B.BookID
    FROM Books as B
    WHERE B.AuthorID = @AuthorID
    ORDER BY B.BookName 
END
GO
```

If you are interested in how to bind the data to your UI, and how to do it without refreshing the UI; then you need to ask a new question about that. It should be specific to your web framework. Generally speaking, if you want web UI update without refresh, you will be using some form of AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is just cascading boxes, you write a `SELECT` query that return the appropriate rows. This is not what a stored procedure does.

```
SELECT * FROM `books` WHERE `author_id` = [author_id]
```

Stored procedures are used to process data, not select it.

Comment: Ok, but i wan to select the values depending upon the item i choose in the combo box, i don't want to select all the values like "select * from" like this.

Comment: "Stored procedures are used to process data, not select it." Well... perhaps in your world that is the case. Where I come from it is a totally different matter. No add hook queries from the client is allowed at all. All queries **has** to be done in SP's.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: Then how i can achieve that one? Can you please tell me.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson are you referring to prepared statements? I can't see how stored procedures would help you select a large resultset.

EDIT: Actually, I see that this has been retagged as sql-server. I'm pretty sure I've come here from 'MySQL'. :/

Comment: @AbdulRahman that's why you limit it with a `WHERE` clause. The `SELECT *` part only selects which *fields* you're selecting, not which *rows*. You can limit that not to be `*`, but we don't know your actual tables.

Comment: @Naltharial - The reason why we use SP's for this is mainly for organizational purposes and control over what queries are executed. Don't like much the idea that there are SQL code scattered and created in client code. Just feel nice to have it in one place. Makes it easy to test and figure out dependencies between queries and tables.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Sites to Start of:

[HOW TO: Call a Parameterized Stored Procedure by Using ADO.NET and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070)

[Calling Stored procedures in ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simplecodeasp.aspx)

[The C# Station ADO.NET Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/lesson01.aspx)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This is how you write a stored procedure that will fetch something for you. I have of course no idea what output you want and what parameters you need so ...

```
create procedure GetBooksByAuthorID
  @AuthorID int
as

select B.BookName,
       B.BookID
from Books as B
where B.AuthorID = @AuthorID
order by B.BookName
```